# How to handle two views in custom UITableViewCell XIB?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have one UIView laid out in UITableViewCell in XIB.

After pressing a button this view should transform into another view (not important how).

The point is, I have to somehow use the second view for making transformation (with same data source) and after transformation exchange those views.

Should I create
- UIView inside the same XIB, 
- second UITableViewCell inside the same XIB, 
- UIView inside another XIB
- UITableViewCell inside another XIB ?

Or maybe something else ?

Comment: By "with same data source" do you mean The data/content displayed inside the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. This was easier, than I thought

I have solved this by putting in XIB:

- UITableViewCell (on top)
- UIView

then connected everything to my custom UITableViewCell class.

My main problem was to synchronize both views with the same data, which I achieved just by copying whatever I needed in UITableViewController.

You just have to remember, that all connections should be between outlet and UITableViewCell and >>NOT<< File's Owner - this somehow crashes app during XIB loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for transitions:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
       duration:0.2
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
       animations:^{ [fromView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:toView]; }
       completion:NULL];
```

In this example (straight from the apple docs), containerView would be your UITableViewCell, and fromView would be a subview of it. toView would be the view to replace it.

About the arrangement of the views insibe de xib, I would stuff them all in the same xib, with fromView as a subview to the tableview cell, and toView without a superview, but connected to the tableview cell (or the files owner) by an outlet.

Comment: Ok, I have to explain more. I have fully custom UITableViewCell. It goes like this: The cell is folded and after user presses a button the cell unfolds. But I have to have screenshot of unfolded view in order to do this, so I have to load this view earlier. After successful animation I want to exchange folded view with unfolded and remove transformed screenshot.

Comment: You could implement a custom transition. The loading of the toView would not be an issue if you keep it in the same xib. The removal of the fromView is also taken care of in the example code.